# Get attributes from java bean

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans

I am new to jstl so this question might sound a bit stupid:
I am trying to use a jsp-tag to get a text from my text-database that is related to a certain key.

It should work kind of like this:

```
<c:getText key="myText" />
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:
I know that there is no such getText-Tag in jstl. its just what i want to do.
I am useing a simple properties-file for my texts. All I need is a way to giva any tag a key and the tag gives me the text that is related to the key.
How can this be done?

Comment: There is no c:getText tag in the JSTL. We don't know what your text database is, but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to write a tag that does what you want. A tag is Java code. If you can do it in Java, you can do it in a custom tag. So the answer to your question is: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is in a `java.util.Properties` object, you don't even need a tag. Store the Properties object in a request attribute (`myProperties`, for example), and use the following EL expression:

```
${myProperties.myText}
```

or, if the key contains characters that can't be used in a Java identifier:

```
${myProperties['my text']}
```

If you still want to write a custom tag, then googling for "custom JST tag" leads to the following tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html

Comment: is there a way to access my Util-Class that handles multiple java.util.Properties? right now i am useing a method that gets a key as parameter...

Comment: If you're using the latest version of the JSP spec, it's probably possible (assuming the method is an instance method and not a static method). And you still have the option of writing a custom tag, provided you take some time to learn from the linked tutorial.